# Redirect file download to another URL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have a client Android app download files directly from a URL, Now I want to redirect download files to an external host. for example I want from my client call file like

```
http://example.com/001.mp3
```

Then my site redirect it to

```
https://archive.org/download/way_002/001.mp3
```

to save my site bandwidth without change URLs on my client app
Thanks

Comment: Redirect to external resource without changing URL? I don't think you can achieve it. If only you create a WebClient in your code to retrieve the file stream and return it to client. However, it still costs bandwidth on your server as server is download files from the real target.

Comment: I found a work around solution, I delete the resources from my site, and change site config to redirect to aspx page in case of error 404, then on page_load of this aspx page I check the URL that directs from, and redirect again to external resource